# Get Absolute path of a url in java

Tags: java, tomcat

Is there a way to retrieve the absolute path of url (http://localhost:8080/myApp) in java. The scenario is, i need to connect to csv file located in tomcat server. The statement works well if I enter the absolute path, but is there a solution to retrieve url's path using getAbsolutePath().Sorry if I'm wrong.

```
Connection conn = DriverManager(getConnection("jdbc:relique:csv:/home/apache-tomcat-6.0.26/webapps/myApp/"))
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`ServletContext.getRealPath()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29), which does exactly what you want.

Note that it does *not* necessarily work in all situations. For example, if your Tomcat is configured to deploy the .war file without unpacking it, then this will return `null`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... The statement you suggested returned an error message "getRealPath(java.lang.String) in javax.servlet.ServletContext cannot be applied to ()"

Comment: You need to pass it a (URL) path relative to your context path. So if you want to know the "root" directory of your webapp, just pass in `"/"`.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. says "Cannot make a static reference to a non-static method".  I am trying to call this from within a spring `@ExceptionHandler` function inside `@ControllerAdvice`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about JAVA.

`May be getServletContext().getContextPath() is something you are looking for`

EDIT:
`Or may be getRealPath()`

Comment: Thanks for your reply...This statement just returns /myApp. But i need something like this... /home/user/apache-tomcat/webapps/myApp

Comment: Well as already told I don't know much about JAVA. What about getServletContext().getRealPath()?

Answer (score -1):

Tomcat is not a http server. All *tomcat urls* reference services, not files.

You'll have to implement another service that sends the csv file on request, if you want to get it through any http URL. URL's like `http://localhost/myapp/input.csv` require a http server like apache httpd.

*(Hope I got your question correct...)*